# How I can join few SQL queries in one? (MS SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

For example I have 4 queries (2 with update and 2 with insert).

```
-- Query 1
UPDATE OrderProduct  
SET Quantity = Quantity + 2,
TotalCost = (Quantity + 2) * Price  
WHERE OrderProductId = 3333

-- Query 2
UPDATE OrderProduct  
SET Quantity = Quantity + 5,
TotalCost = (Quantity + 5) * Price  
WHERE OrderProductId = 4444

-- Query 3
INSERT INTO OrderProduct (ProductName, Quantity, Price, TotalCost)
VALUES ('Some Product', 3, 5.99, 3*5.99);

-- Query 4
INSERT INTO OrderProduct (ProductName, Quantity, Price, TotalCost)
VALUES ('Some Other Product ', 10, 1.99, 10*1.99);
```

Can I join this in one query statement? Maybe by `UNION`?

*P.S. MS SQL hasn't `DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`*

UPD: Or how I can create one `UPDATE` query from two different queries *(like in the example)*? As for `INSERT` - that's easier. I try to reduce ~200 separate queries to one or two queries.

Comment: Have a look at [merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement

Comment: `MS SQL haven't DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` - how is this related to the given code?

Comment: You can merge 2 insert statements into one, not two different updates and 2 inserts. PS: These are not queries, these are `DML operations`, embed all these in a `store proc` and execute them. Merge is like an incremental insert and Update. You can only try looking fro Merge if it suits your needs

Comment: you can combine the two UPDATE statements into one, and the two INSERT statements into one. But you can't combine UPDATE and INSERT into one statement in SQL Server. Maybe you should take a step back and explain us the underlying, actual **problem** you are trying to solve with "merging" the four statements into a single one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the two UPDATE statements into one by using a CASE expression:

```
UPDATE OrderProduct  
   SET Quantity = case OrderProductId
                    when 3333 then Quantity + 2
                    when 4444 then Quantity + 5
                  end, 
       TotalCost = case OrderProductId
                     when 3333 then (Quantity + 2) * Price  
                     when 4444 then (Quantity + 5) * Price  
                   end
WHERE OrderProductId in (3333,4444);
```

The way the CASE expressions are written, it is important that the WHERE clause **only** selects those OrderProductId that are dealt with in the CASE expressions. Otherwise you will set column values to `NULL` for those IDs that you don't handle in the CASE.

Answer (score 1):

If it has to be done 'all or nothing', you could add transactions.

```
BEGIN TRAN

Update 1 
Update 2 
...

COMMIT TRAN
```

This way, either all four (or more) changes are done, or none are done.

If however the reason for your question is less code, perhaps syntax like below could be useful. Or create a temp-table and use a cursor (the sql-version of a for-loop which I normally try to avoid because of performance).

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```